# CompletionHandler Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am a bit confused on how to use completion handlers in Swift 3. Previously, in Swift 2.2, I had code like this:

```
transferUtility.uploadFile(tmpFileURL, bucket: bucket, key: key, contentType: contentType, expression: nil, completionHander: { (task, error) in
                    self.uploadCompletionHandler(task, transferError: error)
})
```

How can I port this to Swift 3?

I get an error that says `Cannot convert value of type '(AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask, NSError) -> ()' to expected argument type 'AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?'`

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the signature of the AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock, now Swift 3 doesn't allow auto type-casting. Swift 3 doesn't allow you to define the completionBlock with different signature, check the `? and !` as well.

Comment: It is `open func uploadFile(_ fileURL: URL, bucket: String, key: String, contentType: String, expression: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression?, completionHander completionHandler: AWSS3.AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock? = nil) -> AWSTask<AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask>`

Comment: and here is `AWS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock`: `public typealias AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock = (AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask, Error?) -> Swift.Void
`

Comment: That doesn't work, it says to put a comma between `error` and `?`. That is obviously not correct.

Comment: Okay try `(task: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadTask, error: Error?)`